# MSP430 Datasheet missing pins

Tags: datasheet, msp430

I have been looking at potential microcontrollers for an upcoming project and I have found that the MSP430FR697x microcontrollers fulfill my requirements. At least, I think they do.

I require at least 3 ADC pins, as well as an external analog + and - reference, and looking through the [DATASHEET](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430fr6927.pdf?ts=1617807281068&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FMSP430FR6927) I can look at the pinout. The one I am evaluating at the moment is the MSP430FR6927, which is one of the 64 pin micros. Looking at page 11 of the datasheet (Figure 4-3) there is a general overview of the pins. On the right hand side, pins 41-48 seem to fulfil this AtoD requirement, it has the analog channels required, plus the external reference inputs.

However, when going down to the pin descriptions in more detail (64 pin "PM" package starts on page 21), when you get to those pins (page 25), the pin descriptions miss out pins 45-48. It jumps from 44 straight to 49.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? I know the datasheet covers a variety of microcontrollers in the same family, but usually they just have some notes if some pins are device specific. I've looked through the datasheet and the [USER GUIDE](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau367p/slau367p.pdf?ts=1617807279633&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FMSP430FR6927) too and can't find any reference to why these pins are excluded.

I am wanting to buy the evaluation board, but don't want to spend that kind of money if the device doesn't do what I need it to.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or does anyone know if this is a common thing and if I can go ahead with evaluating this microcontroller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a documentation error - I'm shocked! Get in touch with the sales department, they're usually pretty responsive to these sorts of thing, even for low quantity potential orders. Will they fix it in another release? Less likely; it takes a lot of effort to do a new document release, and they're not going to re-issue for a small oversight like this even if it seems like a fairly major omission when you're trying to work with the part.

Comment: Thanks for this, I thought it may be somethign like that, but wanted to be sure I wasn't missing anything. I managed to find another datasheet here: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430fr6972.pdf?ts=1617807176851&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F which states it includes the FR692x series, but doesn't specify the FR6927 (like the datasheet linked in the question). This one has information for these "missing" pins on page 16..... As it doesn;t include the specific model I am looking at, it's a bit annoying!

Comment: @MCG Yes - very frustrating indeed. Glass half full take: at least it's just missing rather than incorrect. That's even more frustrating..!

Comment: Absolutely correct. I'm drafting an email to our TI representative to see if they can shed some light on it. I'll accept this answer if there are no alternative replies before I get an email response.

Comment: Managed to hear back from the TI rep after he talked to the people looking after the documentation and it was indeed missing information. However, those pins (P9.4 - P9.7) are indeed the analog inputs I had presumed from the pinout diagram.

Comment: Good stuff @MCG, glad you got a response from them :)